# Check identical consecutive groups with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex to detect if a telephone number is a nice looking number.
Some examples are:

- Numbers that end with 2 groups of 3 consecutive numbers (e.g. 32 xx 123 123)
- Numbers that end with 6 times the same number (e.g. 32 50 11 11 11)
- Numbers that end with 3 of 4 groups of consecutive numbers
  (e.g. 32 50 12 12 12 or 32 12 12 12 12)
- Numbers that end with 2 groups of consecutive numbers (e.g. 32 50 120 120)

Is this possible with a regular expression? e.g. how could you indicate in this regex:

```
([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})
```

That the last 2 matches need to be identical in order for it to be a valid match?

Comment: Using capture groups perhaps?

Comment: Try this https://regex101.com/r/IhbcPd/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^(?:\d+ )*?((\d{2,3})(?: \2){1,3})$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/KU5Eoz/2). It will match any digit/space groups at the start of the string, and then caputure repeating chunks of two or three digits separated with a single space. `\s` will match any whitespace and `\s+` will match any one or more whitespace characters, replace the space in the pattern if you wish to have any whitespace support.